Purchased Osmium sample - Legitimate or fake?
I recently bought a troy ounce of Osmium beads from China. When I opened the package, I was surprised to not see shiny bluish metal, but instead beads resembling dull grey lead and some dark grey powder lightly coating the bag. The metal is heavy.
My initial thinking is that one of two things happened. The first is that I got sent a sample that was not handled properly in the lab. Certainly not vacuum arc melted and exposed to a lot of heat & oxygen, and therefore a significant amount of oxidization ocurred. The other possibility is that I got scammed and was sent lead, because it has high density and might be mistaken for oxidized osmium.
It should be easy to test if it's lead, due to melting point and malleability. I figure most other high density metals wouldn't be worth passing off as Osmium?
I was speaking with someone who is insistent that it could not be Osmium. They stated that Osmium does not tarnish when oxidized and that there is no reason for there to be powder in the bag, because Osmium is hard and no powder should come off even with friction.
Any idea of what's happened here? Here is a picture:


Do remember that osmium tetroxide sublimates and is teratogenic.

Check the density.

Osmium is very dangerous and should be kept in well closed container, away from oxygen and open air access. The molecule [OsO4]  easily binds with oils in our body, irritating the skin, nose, and throat. It’ll also burn the eyes, but it won’t stop there: it also permanently stains the corneas, rendering a person blind. Even at concentrations too low to smell — roughly two parts per billion — it can cause a fatal buildup of fluid in the lungs or damage the kidneys.  More at episodictable.com - osmium

Maybe you got th chemical wuivalent of a knock-off. What was advertised as osmium may have  been an alloy containing said osmium. It would be cheaper and less dangerous in that form.

@OscarLanzi - such as platinum-osmium which is perfectly safe and many people use daily in the form of ballpoint pens.

Did you try to smell it?

Only with eye protection, maybe? I still "smell" an alloy yhey're calling osmium.

Very easy to calculate if it is real or not. At this time, the price of osmium metal is about 1,500 €/gram or ~US$44,000/oz. Is that about what you paid?
If you paid significantly less, it likely is not Os.
Caveat emptor
